# Cannot find directory at boot

Tags: android, file, boot, android-sdcard

In my application, I create a service that aims to read something from sd card.

The service is created and started at boot time.

The problem is that  although I am pretty sure that the directory exists, at the boot time, the service cannot find the directory.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Context context=getBaseContext();
    File sdDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/temp/Data/");
    if(!sdDir.exists()){
        sdDir.mkdir();
        Toast.makeText(this, "CAN'T FIND!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
```

This snippet above outputs

1. Service Started
2. CAN'T FIND!

At first, I thought that sd card might not be mounted at boot time and that's why the service can't find the directory. I am still not sure about that.

Anybody has an idea? What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some devices take time to mount the SD card. It may not be available immediately after Boot time.

Just poll every few seconds until it becomes available.

Also try this:

```
public static boolean hasStorage(boolean requireWriteAccess) {  
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();  

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {  
        return true;  
    } else if (!requireWriteAccess  && Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {  
        return true;  
    }  
    return false;  
}
```

[From Here](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2010/04/15/android-check-if-sd-card-storage-is-available/)